# Image loses responsiveness if combined with link_to in Rails 5 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Adding link_to on an image_tag breaks image responsiveness in a rails 5 app using bootstrap 3. The image initially resizes fine using the img-responsive class but breaks when I try to convert it to a link. Same holds true if I replace the img-responsive class with my own class. In the interest of being thorough, I tried all the suggested fixes I've found regarding general img-responsive issues (i.e. add col-xs-12 class, making sure image-width is 100%, wrapping the image in a div...) but the problem isn't a problem until I add link_to so, as expected, none of them worked. I've included the html in case I'm missing something in the layout but this seems like a rails issue. BTW, the other image, 'tag-line.png' that is not a link, scales fine. I should also mention this happens across all browsers. Anyone else have this problem? Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

```
<header>
    <div id="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
         <%=link_to image_tag("header-logo.png", size: "560 x 85", alt: 
           "company logo"), root_path, class: "img-responsive" %>
         </div>    
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= image_tag "tag-line.png", size: "380 x 20", alt: "tag line", 
       class: "tag-line img-responsive" %>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I got around this by wrapping an anchor tag around the image tag but the html it put out is almost identical.

Comment: The only difference was href = "/" when using the code above and href= "https://my_url" when using external anchor tag. If I replace root_path with the actual url when using the above code, the html output is exactly the same as it is with the a tags, but it it's not responsive. Seems like the link_to is the culprit. Glad I found a work-around but, being a rails newbie, I'd be interested if anyone has an explanation.